# Postgresql fails to start with no such file or directory error?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, init.d

I was juggling Postgresql versions and I think I shot myself in the foot during the renaming of something.  I have 9.3 and 9.4 installed on an Ubuntu 14.04 station, and I wanted to go back to 9.3 so I did some "file surgery" to make this happen.  Somewhere along the line, I guess I did a rename and now when I issue the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

I get the following error output:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                             
* Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.3-main.bak.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.3-main.bak.service' for details.

[fail]
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server                                                                                                     
* Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.4-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.4-main.service' for details.
```

I executed the systemctl status command as indicated by the error output for 9.3 and got this:

```
postgresql@9.3-main.bak.service
Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

As you can see from the **main.bak.service** output line, somehow postgresql picked up the rename.  (*However, I don't see a file named "service" anywhere in the directory tree.*)

I looked inside my configuration file for postgresql and I don't see that directory anywhere:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'     # use data in another directory
                # (change requires restart)
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf'   # host-based authentication file
                # (change requires restart)
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_ident.conf'   # ident configuration file
                # (change requires restart)
```

I don't have a PGROOT or PGDATA environment variable set so I don't think that's it?  Also, as you can see from the command I use to start postgresql, I am not specifying a configuration file explictly.  Is there a bad symlink somewhere that I don't know about?  How can I fix this?

**Where is postgresql picking up the main.bak.service file reference from?**

Also, should I be using starting postgresql using the **postgresql** account instead of **root** (su vs sudo)?  My setup used to work before so I fouled things up so I don't think that is the problem if running as root is a bad thing.  But I would like to know the right user account to use when launching postgresql.